# What's the difference between "...THE English bookstores in Paris" and "...English bookstores in Paris"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is it okay to use "the" before "English bookstores" in the following sentence? If yes, how is it different from a sentence without "the"?

> You can buy it from the English bookstores in Paris.

> You can buy it from English bookstores in Paris.

Comment: Using _the_ suggests that the speaker knows how many English bookstores there are in Paris and is thinking of them as a group; without _the_ is a bit more vague - 'any English bookstores there may be'.

Comment: I would use *the* here only if I were confident that **every** English bookstore in Paris sells it.  Without an article, the sentence implies that most E.b.i.P. have it, but does not promise certainty as to any one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If someone says, "You can buy it from the English bookstore in Paris", the sentence implies there is only one, or one specific, book store in Paris.
If they say, "The English bookstores" in Paris, it would imply that Paris is somehow known for its bookstores... they are special enough to warrant 'the'.
What someone would normally say is "... from an English bookstore in Paris' or, depending on the situation, "... and English bookstore when we get to (or go to) Paris."
I want to say that you can't say "from English Bookstores in Paris", but you can. It would be an odd context. Perhaps...
John: I would really like to get this book, but I can't find it at any of the local French bookstores.
Sue: You can get it from English bookstores in Paris.

That is doable... but I wouldn't recommend anyone but a native speaker try it.